# Files missing after batch-renaming through python (os.rename)

Tags: python, python-3.x, batch-rename, renaming

I wrote a python script to rename all the JPG and jpeg files present in a particular folder.

I changed my directory to the folder which contained all the jpg, JPG files and a rename.py ( which is the script that I wrote ).

```
import os
cwd=os.getcwd()
for file in os.listdir(cwd):
    i=1
    if file.endswith('.JPG') or file.endswith('.jpeg'):
        new=str(i)+'.JPG'
        os.rename(file, new)
        i+=1
```

After running the script all the JPG and jpeg files went missing.(Edit:except 1.JPG)
Why did this happen and how do I recover the files?

Comment: Why is `i=1` inside the loop? It should be before the for loop. You will get a `FileExistsError` exception otherwise.

Comment: Ya, i=1 should be outside the loop. I forgot to mention that 1.JPG still remains in the directory(I've edited the question accordingly). So what I think happened is instead of throwing  'FileExistsError', for each iteration the image got renamed to 1.JPG and replaced the existing 1.JPG. I don't think there's a way to recover my images since the got replaced. Please do tell me if there's any method to recover them.